# Where are open air railway carriages used in scheduled services?

Tags: trains, where-on-earth

In summer, [*die kleine rote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhaetian_Railway) uses [open scenic carriages](https://www.rhb.ch/en/leisure-travel-and-excursions/groups-schools/charter-carriages/open-scenic-carriages) on the [Bernina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernina_railway) railway, in regular scheduled train services.

[image: Aussichtswagen]
*Offene Aussichtswagen* / *Carrozze panoramici aperti* / *Vagun panoramic*.  Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RhB_vagun_panoramic_at_Poschiavo,_16_Aug_2014.JPG)

I used to enjoy those as a child, but I've never seen them anywhere else since.  Are similar open carriages used in scheduled train services (thus not including museum railways or special events) anywhere else on Earth?

Comment: From the [Wikimedia Commons open railway coaches category](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Open_railway_coaches), it appears the [*Train Jaune*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_de_Cerdagne) may have them as well, but more generally [Open coach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_coach) has a different meaning, making it hard to google.

Comment: Probably too broad. I can think of a couple in NZ alone, plus at least one in North America...